# how to transpose 2 variables gameobject type in unity c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if (rotateInProgres) {
    //parent.transform.Rotate (0, 90, 0);
    parent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(parent.transform.rotation, r, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    transfer = cube6.transform.gameObject;
    transfer2= cube3.transform.gameObject;
    cube3.transform.gameObject = transfer.gameObject;
    rotateInProgres = false;
}
```

I want to transpose but I have error in line 7, `cube3.transform.gameObject = transfer.gameObject;`

Comment: OK I'll bite - what is the error? Maybe posting that would help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

GameObjects are the "top" of the object hierarchy here.  You can't change a transform's `gameObject` field because that field refers to the GameObject that it is attached to and you can't detach a component from a game object without destroying it.

If you want to make two GameObjects *switch places* you need to alter their `trasnform.position` properties:

```
    Vector3 transfer_pos = cube6.transform.position;
    Vector3 transfer2_pos = cube3.transform.position;
    cube3.transform.position = transfer_pos;
    cube6.transform.position = transfer2_pos;
```